# SWRevealViewController pushing back to front view controller showing error

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController for preparing a slide menu. On clicking `WishList` cell in my side bar it moves to its corresponding VC. I have my front view controller with storyboardID - "LandingPage". Now when I move to the WishList page I have a back button pressing on which user returns to the already set front view controller. I am using the following approaches but without any success.

**1.Using normal `presentViewController:()` method**

```
 @IBAction func backButton(sender: AnyObject)
    {

            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LandingPage")
           self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }

    }
```

But this results in an error in `viewDidLoad()` in `LandingPageVC` as -

[image]

and error message reads - `"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`

**2.By setting a navigation controller and front VC.**

```
 @IBAction func backButton(sender: AnyObject)
    {

        if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LandingPage") as? LandingPageViewController
        {
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            navController.setViewControllers([vc], animated:true)
            self.revealViewController().setFrontViewController(navController, animated: true)
        }

    }
```

Here I get the following error -

[image]

and error message reads - `"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`

So what mistake am I doing in my approach and how to move to the already set front VC ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check once your reveal view is available or not

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Sorry,couldn't get you. How to do so? My slide is working fine expect this part.